# ¿ Como utilizar el "formalismo puntero" para calcular la media de una tabla?

Tags: c++, punteros

Tengo un ejercicio en C++/C para hacer la media de un array utilisando el "formalismo puntero" ("formalisme pointeur" en francés). Por ejemplo este siguiente utiliza el "formalismo puntero" para manipular la tabla :

```
int tab[10];

for{int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ )
{
   *(tab + i) = 0
}
```

Pero este utiliza el "formalismo tabla" :

```
int tab[10];

for{int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i ++ )
{
   tab[i] = 0
}
```

**No entiendo bien si hacen la misma cosa**...

Sin embargo **he hecho el siguiente para calcular la media de une tabla de 10 numeros con el "formalismo tabla" ¿ como hacerlo con el "formalismo puntero" ?**

```
#include<iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Écrire, de deux manières différentes, un programme qui lit 10 nombres entiers et les stocke dans un tableau statique de taille 10 avant de calculer la media des éléments de ce tableau

void mediaTableau(int tabula[]){

    int media = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<sizeof(tabula); i++){
        media = tableauEntiers[i] +moyenne;
    }

    cout << "media tabula " << media/sizeof(tabula) <<endl;
}

int main(){

    static int tabula[10];

    cout << "Da diez numeros" <<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            cin >> tabula[i];
            cout << "numero " << i+1 <<endl;
        }

        mediaTableau(tabula);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Te he cambiado la etiqueta, de C a C++, que es el lenguaje en el que está escrito el código que muestras.

Comment: [Esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/803/por-qu%c3%a9-la-expresi%c3%b3n-indicearreglo-es-equivalente-a-arregloindice) y [esta otra](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46473/como-puedo-pasar-un-array-bidimensional-de-integers-a-una-funci%c3%b3n-void-para-pode/46708#46708) pueden serte de ayuda :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente,

```
tabla[indice] == *( puntero + indice )
```

es una de las facilidades de C/C++ para trabajar con punteros, que te permite trabajar con ellos de la forma que te sea más comoda. Te permite *abstraer* el *uso lógico* (como organices tus datos) del *uso físico* (como el compilador maneja los datos en memoria).

Respecto a tu pregunta, has de cambiar tu función `mediaTableau( )`, añadiéndole un nuevo argumento: la longitud de la tabla, puesto que los punteros **no proporcionan** esa información:

```
void mediaTableau( int *tabula, size_t size ){
  int media = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
    media += *( tabula + i );

  cout << "media tabula " << media / size <<endl;
}
```

Y, consecuentemente, has de cambiar el modo de llamarla, indicando *explicitamente* el tamaño **en elementos** de la misma:

```
mediaTableau( tabula, sizeof( tabula ) / sizeof( tabula[0] ) );
```

**EDITO**

Tal y como indicas en los comentarios, un *arreglo* no es mas que una sucesión de elementos en memoria; cuando nosotros hacemos algo como

```
int lista[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

el compilador genera en memoria exactamente lo que parece, una secuencia de 5 datos de tipo `int`, con los valores que le indicamos:

> | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |

El concepto de *arreglo* o *array* **no existe** en el núcleo de los lenguajes C / C++. No son más que secuencias de bytes, y, en el ejemplo indicado, `lista` no es mas que un *puntero* a esa secuencia de bytes que el compilador genera.

Lo anterior es para la *declaración* de variables. Para su uso, los conceptos *puntero* y *array* son *intercambiables*, y permiten lo que ya vimos en la pregunta:

> lista[0] == *lista == *( lista + 0 )
>   lista[1] == *( lista + 1 ) == lista[0][1]
>   lista[2] == *( lista + 2 ) == lista[0][2] == lista[1][1]

Ante expresiones del tipo

```
variable[indice1][indice2]...[indiceN]
```

el compilador las interpreta como

```
*( variable + ( indice1 + indice2 + ... + indiceN ) )
```

E incluso se permiten los *índices* **negativos**

```
variable[-1] == *( variable - 1 )
```

**Cuidadito** con lo que hacemos. Tanta libertad tiene un precio: el compilador **no comprueba los índices que usamos**. Desde su punto de vista, *allá nosotros*. Si hacemos

```
lista[100] = 0
```

estaremos escribiendo *fuera del bloque de memoria* al que apunta `lista`, y provocaremos cualquier *cosa curiosa*. Desde errores del sistema operativo, hasta cambiar el valor de otras variables.

Comment: ;) por cierto no sucedan las variables a cruzcar las montanas o el oceano Atlantico ;)
¿ Entonces las direcciones de los elementos de la tabula se
crean una tras otra en la memoria ?

Comment: @Marine1 respuesta editada.