# Arreglos unidimensionales en C++

Tags: c++, array

¿Para qué sirven los arreglos unidimensionales?

```
int Temp[12];
```

Comment: Bienvenido para que sea bien recibida tu pregunta por la comunidad te invito a leer [ask] y editar la pregunta sengun los consejos que se te dan ahi

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Para qué sirven los arreglos unidimensionales?

Para lo que sirvan dependerá del uso que se les de. Por sus características pueden ser útiles en diferentes contextos.

#### Características.

- Almacenan datos de un tipo determinado de manera contigua en memoria.
- Se consideran un [agregado](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/inicializadores-de-miembros-en-agregados/), aunque el tipo almacenado no lo sea.
- Requieren que el tipo almacenado sea [construible por defecto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_default_constructible).
- Decaen automáticamente a puntero al tipo almacenado.
- El nombre del arreglo es equivalente a un puntero al primer elemento del mismo, pudiendo aplicar aritmética de punteros.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Es posible que un arreglo unidimensional no se ajuste a tus necesidades, C++ ofrece otros contenedores de datos a los que tal vez quieras echar un vistazo, consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54180/en-qu%C3%A9-escenario-debo-usar-cada-contenedor-stl) para más información.
- Con cierta aritmética puedes simular un arreglo multidimensional usando uno unidimensional, consulta [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46473/como-puedo-pasar-un-array-bidimensional-de-integers-a-una-funci%C3%B3n-void-para-pode/46708#46708) para más detalles al respecto.

Answer (score 1):

En los Arreglos unidimensionales podemos acceder a cualquier elemento de este sin tener que consultar a elementos anteriores o posteriores, esto mediante el uso de un índice para cada elemento del arreglo que nos da su posición relativa.

```
int miarreglo[10]
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    miarreglo[i]=i*10;

cout<<miarreglo[5]; //50
```